# Just updated the apt package on 16.04, now any apt command gives me a relocation error

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

Running apt update gives me this,

```
apt: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0:
symbol _ZN9pkgSystem9LockInnerEv, version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file
libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference
```

In an attempt to fix this, I downloaded the apt package from [here on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/apt/download), installed it with `dpkg`, ran `apt upgrade` and that told me to fix it with `-f`. I did that and it brought me back to the original issue. I assume there is a library issue here, but I am not sure what I need to update.

When I asked on reddit I was advised to reinstall; is this the best way to resolve this issue?

Any ideas on where to look or what to do to fix this?

As I cannot do this with `apt`, I would need to `wget` and `dpkg` any packages required to fix this, so please link me to the relevant sources, if applicable.

EDIT, I have contacted the Ubuntu bugtracker questions team and found a temporary fix, https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/675775

Comment: This has been reported as a bug in 16.04: [apt failed to run due to link time reference error](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1644643).

Comment: Haha! Oh, okay. I've been pulling my hair out over the past few days, trying to work out what's going on. Never occurred to me it was a bug, or to look on the bugtracker. Thanks :-)

Comment: Just confirmed the bug, hopefully others will find this and say it affects them too.

Comment: This is the second time this bug was reported on Ask Ubuntu today. Thanks for confirming the bug.

Comment: Try these commands,
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libapt-pkg5.0_1.2.29_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg --install --force-downgrade libapt-pkg5.0_1.2.29_amd64.deb

Comment: If you're using Zentyal, don't forget to hold that package back with `sudo apt-mark hold libapt-pkg5.0` otherwise it'll break after the next update.

Answer (score 3):

Today I had same problem after simple `apt update && apt upgrade`.

And i fixed it replacing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0.0` from another Ubuntu 16.04 installation.

Comment: You can also try this https://gist.github.com/xiaojueguan/e3570667b5f90bda351b3228c18ad846